# How to run "docker-machine create" in OS X?

Tags: macos, docker

I started Docker and am now following the tutorial, but for all I know I couldn't run the `docker-machine` command on OS X.

[The documentation states](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted-voting-app/node-setup/) that you run the following command to create a local virtual machine:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox manager
```

However, this command doesn't work in OS X (11.6), with the following error:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"
```

I tried to install the virtualbox; however, [another page clearly states](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#/what-to-know-before-you-install) that you must not install it on your local machine:

> VirtualBox prior to version 4.3.30 must NOT be installed (it is incompatible with Docker for Mac)
>
> Note: If your system does not satisfy these requirements, you can install Docker Toolbox, which uses Oracle VirtualBox instead of HyperKit.

So I only installed *Docker for Mac* and not virtualbox. So what am I missing here? [The example page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted-voting-app/#/got-docker) says you can run the tutorial on OS X, so I wonder how I can proceed...

> You can follow along and run this example using Docker for Mac, Docker for Windows or Docker for Linux.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same issue today and resolved it by installing VirtualBox as an additional step after installing Docker for Mac (I did so with `brew install --cask virtualbox`)

I don't recall having to do the extra install previously, but maybe I already had VirtualBox already installed because of another tool (like Vagrant). Anyway, this is explained in the [Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/) documentation:

> **If you are using Docker for Mac**
>
> Docker for Mac uses HyperKit, a lightweight macOS virtualization
> solution built on top of the Hypervisor.framework in macOS 10.10
> Yosemite and higher.
>
> Currently, there is no docker-machine create driver for HyperKit, so
> you will use virtualbox driver to create local machines. (See the
> Docker Machine driver for Oracle VirtualBox.) Note that you can run
> both HyperKit and Oracle VirtualBox on the same system. To learn more,
> see Docker for Mac vs. Docker Toolbox.
>
> - **Make sure you have the latest VirtualBox correctly installed on your system (either as part of an earlier Toolbox install, or manual
>   install)**.

Comment: I think now you need brew install --cask virtualbox rather than brew install cask virtualbox because of the update.

Comment: Updated command to reflect the change @GloriaChen, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. At the same spot ;-)
For me the xhyve driver, available from https://github.com/zchee/docker-machine-driver-xhyve, worked.
In short:

```
brew install docker-machine-driver-xhyve
```

You get a notice some links need to be created manually, so copy those and execute

```
sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/opt/docker-machine-driver-xhyve/bin/docker-machine-driver-xhyve
sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/opt/docker-machine-driver-xhyve/bin/docker-machine-driver-xhyve
```

Create:

```
docker-machine create --driver xhyve manager
```

Without VirtualBox. Im using OS X 10.11.6, too.

Answer (score 0):

After updating my docker `docker-machine` command stopper working on my mac terminal.

So found after updating my docker I'll have to reinstall `docker-machine` CLI just to get the latest version.
Updated docker-machine to latest one using the command below helped me making docker-machine command working again.

```
base=https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0 &&
curl -L $base/docker-machine-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) >/usr/local/bin/docker- 
machine &&
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

See Docs (https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/#install-machine-directly)