# Docker issues on Mac

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I installed docker using HomeBrew on Mac.

```
➜  mattermost-server git:(master) docker --version
Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90

➜  mattermost-server git:(master) which docker
/usr/local/bin/docker
```

When I run docker, 
This is the error I get.

**➜  mattermost-server git:(master) docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at **unix:///var/run/docker.sock.**

Is the docker daemon running?**

Update: This can be solved by removing existing docker and running 
brew install cask docker 
Refer here [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084846/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-on-macos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem after install docker on my mac (`brew cask install docker`).

`docker --version works`, but docker ps or any other docker command results in the error:
**Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?**

To solve the problem you have to :

1. Install Virtual Box
2. run :  `docker-machine create default`  to create a virtual machine (mandatory 
   on  mac os)
3. run: `docker-machine env default` to set the environment
4. run: `eval $(docker-machine env default)`

try `docker ps` or `docker version` to check that everything is ready.

Answer (score 1):

You are possibly running docker without `sudo` user, aren't you?

By default you should run docker with `sudo` user, if you don't want to do that, folow [Manage Docker as a non-root user](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user)

Comment: ➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ sudo docker ps
Password:
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: For mac, I suggest to use https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac, try it if you are not using it right now.

Answer (score -1):

We need to run `brew cask install docker`. This should fix the problem.