# Run docker daemon from pycharm

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I've just started to use docker and got an error.
I use Pycharm on macOS. In my project I clone a github repo (that's a simple LogisticRegression from sklearn) that includes dockerfile.
I expected, that all what I needed was

```
docker build . -t servername
```

But I got an error

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Where should i run Docker daemon?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Vote to close as this is likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084846/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-on-macos?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084846/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-on-macos)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install and run Docker first. Here is the Link for [Docker Desktop for MacOS](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/install/).

Answer (score 0):

Run it with `sudo` so `sudo docker build . -t servername`

else try `sudo systemctl enable docker.service && systemctl enable containerd.service`