# Docker demon doesn't start on Mac

Tags: docker

I know there is already hundreds of posts speaking of problems that look like this one, but I haven't managed to find an answer to my problem.

- I run docker on a Apple M1
- I downloaded the dmg from https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/ and installed it (successfully I guess)
- I installed rosetta 2 just in case
- It run in my bar with a green status
- I've even created an account and I'm logged in

But in my terminal I still have the Error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

When I use the UI to install an image, it seems to work fine and the image is running, but even the embedded terminal is failing.

[image: Failing to connect to docker deamon]

I'm running short on ideas right now, does someone has a solution please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution at last:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74148162/3415828

That question was asked in 2017 but the thread is still active. @efriis spotted that since 4.13, docker doesn't create the symlink to /var/run/docker.sock by default.

Since the answer was quite hidden in an old topic, it may be relevant to raise it here. @efriis if you read me, I let you create the question yourself with the answer and I will delete that one.