# How can I make Docker API calls on my local Mac?

Tags: docker

I'd like to learn how to use the [Eixo::Docker](https://metacpan.org/dist/Eixo-Docker/view/lib/Eixo/Docker.pod) Perl module to make local Docker API calls on my machine, a Mac Book Pro running Docker Desktop version 4.26.1.

I added this line to the `~/.docker/config.json`:

`"hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"]`

Also tried a few other iterations to this entry but when I restart Docker Desktop, this line gets wiped out.

Comment: The unencrypted TCP option you're showing here is **incredibly dangerous**: anyone who can access the Docker socket can trivially take over the entire host system, and so you _really_ don't want to make it network-accessible.  If the library you're trying to use requires this, I'd consider that a critical bug, and I might look for a library that can use the standard Unix socket.  (I'd also be concerned that the installation instructions you link to have a decade-old copyright and recommend an obsolete Ubuntu version.)

Comment: I’m just running this on my local machine.

Comment: Can anyone confirm if https://stackoverflow.com/a/49719638/1641112 is accurate?

Comment: Docker Desktop is a newer approach to run a Linux VM for Docker.  The fundamentals of that answer are still true, but Docker Machine isn't in widespread use any more.  (I generally use Minikube with a Hyperkit backend on a MacOS host...but again, to run a Linux VM to run Docker on a non-Linux host.)

Comment: I dont' know what the F* and of that means. I just want to set up images and containers programmatically on a mac. Maybe I'll just continue using wrappers to "docker" commands.